# Twitter does not return email id after whitelisting in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter

My app is whitelist and i am getting accesses email id option in permission as well. i used below code still i am getting nil in email.

```
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {
    TWTRShareEmailViewController* shareEmailViewController =
    [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
     initWithCompletion:^(NSString* email, NSError* error) {
         NSLog(@"Email %@, Error: %@", email, error);
     }];
    [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
} else {
    // TODO: Handle user not signed in (e.g.
    // attempt to log in or show an alert)
}
```

where to put this line of code

Answer (score 0):

If you get whitelisted and still not getting email you might have different consumer api key and consumer secret key of fabric and twitter. Follow these steps:

1. Go to Keys and Access token in Application settings of twitter.
2. Copy the whitelisted keys from there, of consumer api and consumer secret keys.
3. Go to plist file in Xcode and replace the same under fabric in plist.